# WCF Client and Firewall

Tags: wcf, firewall

I have an annoying problem with a WCFClient that communicates to remote WCF Service.

On some machines (W7), the client connects OK, but on others, the client hangs whenever a function on the server is called.

The service url is "http://192.168.1.23:8091/CIPService"

On one particular client, I've dropped it off the domain and turned off the firewall and it connects OK.

So firewall issue?

I reinstate the firewall, add the WCF Client to the firewall exception list (on all network types), I add incoming and outgoing rules to allow the port (8091) through but still the client just hangs.

On the server side, TCPView shows (with the firewall turned ON (!)) a connection on port 8091 coming in when the client connects and bytes being sent and received.

So, turning the firewall off sorts matters, firewall on, exceptions and rules in place and the client cannot connect to the service (but TCPView shows a connection to the port being made).

I'm completely confused by this and out of ideas of how to proceed. Can someone please suggest how I move forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Port 80. Make sure it's open.....